# Why am I lost the WSO2 APIM Store session after click in all API?

Tags: nginx, wso2, reverse-proxy, wso2-api-manager

I have an specific node for my APIM store which is configured for https://mydomain.store.
        I'm using nginx for front-end all APIM nodes or cluster. And for almost every thing its running fine.
        The problem is: **After access the I lost the session every time that I click on all available API.**.
        In my opinion it is a problem with NGINX. If a config Store to maintain original context (https://mydomain.store/store) i don´t have problems. 
        After all my research, my nginx config files are:

```
upstream loja{
        server localhost:9443;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.store;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/lojahml.log ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-lojahml;

    #SSL CONFIG
    ...


    location /{
        proxy_set_header X-WSO2-Tenant "carbon.super";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_pass https://loja/store/;
        proxy_redirect  https://loja/store/ https://mydomain.store;
        proxy_cookie_path /store /;

    }
     location /carbon{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/carbon;

    }

   location ~ ^/(.*)registry/(.*)$ {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/$1registry/$2;
   }

   location /registry {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/registry;
   }

   location /services{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/services;

   }

}
```

The site.json for store jaggery APP is like that:

```
...
"reverseProxy" : {
    "enabled" : "true",    // values true , false , "auto" - will look for  X-Forwarded-* headers
    "host" : "mydomain.store", // If reverse proxy do not have a domain name use IP
    "context":"",
    //"regContext":"" // Use only if different path is used for registry
  },
...
```

P.S.   Before everything running fine using apache as front-end.